# Data section in a.out

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, systems-programming

here is a simple code that I executed

```
int a;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Then after compiling with gcc I did

```
size a.out
```

I got some output in bss and data section...Then I changed my code to this

```
int a;
int main()
{
    char *p = "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Again when I saw the output by size a.out after compiling , size of data section remained same..But we know that string hello will be allocated memory in read only initialized part..Then why size of data section remained same?

Comment: Probably either because it's never being used or because the data section is padded.

Comment: Most likely compiled out

Comment: +1 from this question i know about size a.out ...!!!!

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

It gives

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    960     248       8    1216     4c0 a.out
```

---

when you do

```
int a;
int main()
{
    char *p = "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

it gives

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    982     248       8    1238     4d6 a.out
```

at that time hello is stored in `.rodata` and the location of that address is stored in char pointer `p` but here p is stored on stack

and size doesnt shows stack. And i am not sure but .rodata is here calculated in text or dec.

---

when you write

```
int a;
char *p = "hello";
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

it gives

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    966     252       8    1226     4ca a.out
```

now here again "hello" is stored in .rodata but char pointer takes 4 byte and stored in data so data is increment by 4

For more info http://codingfreak.blogspot.in/2012/03/memory-layout-of-c-program-part-2.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually, that's an implementation detail. The compiler works by an as-is principle. Meaning that as long as the behavior of the program is the same, it's free to exclude any piece of code it wants. In this case, it can skip `char* p = "hello"` altogether.

Comment: but when i added printf("%s\",s) then size only increased by 4

Comment: @user1205088 the call to printf probably.

Comment: As long as you use -O0 (default) on gcc, it will not exclude code (at least as far as I know).

Answer (score 2):

The string "hello" is allocated in the section `.rodata`

Comment: @user1205088 just do "grep hello" on your binary file and see if it is thrown away by compiler or not :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if the total size doesn't changed, it doesn't mean that the code didn't.

I tested your example.
The string "hello" is a constant data, thus it is stored in the readonly .rodata section.
You can see this particular section using objdump, for example: 
`objdump -s -j .rodata <yourbinary>`

With gcc 4.6.1 without any options, I got for your second code:

```
Contents of section .rodata:
 4005b8 01000200 68656c6c 6f00               ....hello.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use that `char *` in your code, the compiler optimized it away.